# Publishing .NET MVC website to MONO on Synology NAS

Tags: nas, .net-framework, synology, mvc

I'm not able to figure out how I can host a simple MVC 4 or MVC 3 website to my Synology DS413J.
I installed MONO V2.11, this is still in beta on the Synology. After installing and running this I went to Control panel> applications> web services and activated Enable web station and enable personal website int he web services tab.

After enabeling this you will have more folders in your directory. You can place your .html pages in the web folder and you will be able to access them from another computer.

Then I just made a simple C# MVC application where the view has "hello world".
I published this NAS/web/test. If I put and simple html file in this location I can run the page from my browser on another computer. If I go to `http://ip/test/`
I get the message "Sorry, the page you are looking for is not found." Note. The ip doesn't has a port defined because its default 80.

I know in IIS you need to define the path in a config file, maybe I still need to do this on my Synology but I have no idea how. Also didn't find a lot of information on this topic for Synology file systems.

How can I host a .NET website on my Synology DS413J?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a Mono (Beta) Package Version 3.4.0-1 on Synocommunity. Don't forget to enable Beta-Packages in your Synology Package Center Settings. Otherwise you won't see these packages.

Answer (score 2):

Mono (Beta) Package Version 3.4.0-1 from Synocommunity does not work in web applications.
Synology's own 2.11.1 does work with web, but only up to .NÉT 3.5

I would suggest to create a simple index.html on your page to see if your web server is in fact running and your are able to access it through firewalls etc.
To start with an advanced .NET is ambitious ;-P